# Returning the y value of a drawline

Tags: teechart

Is there any way to get the y value of a drawline. I can get the only start and end position.

I try to catch the chance when a candle of moving financial series breaks through a drawline.

Comment: Which TeeChart version are you using: VCL, .NET, Java, ActiveX, PHP, Android, MonoTouch, MonoDroid, Javascript, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as in the *All Features\Welcome !\Chart styles\Standard\Line(Strip)\Interpolating line series* included in the features demo in most TeeChart versions. This example is based in the interpolating examples I made here:

TeeChart VCL & Delphi: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=2828
TeeChart ActiveX * VB6: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=4161

If more specific information is required please let us know the TeeChart version you are using.